# SLSQP - Inequality constraints incompatible

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization

Im doing an optimization using SLSQP however it always returns "Inequality constraints incompatible".

I think my criterion are fine:

```
g1 = a_lower - a # a is of length 10
g2 = b_lower - b # b is of length 10
```

The initial values dont satisfy all conditions tho.

I'm using pyOpt. I'm totally confused by this error message.

Could anyone help?

Comment: Could you please post a minimum reproducible example, aka code that we can run ourselves to reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 8):

The constrained optimization algorithms in the scipy.optimize module are assumed to satisfy ">=0". Assuming that your `a_lower` and `b_lower` values are the lower limits of `a` and `b`, I think the constraints `g1` and `g2` should be

`g1 = a - a_lower
g2 = b - b_lower`

My apologies if I'm completely misreading your dilemma.